# Aggregate pipeline works when used directly but not when passed via Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm writing this query on Python (3.8) to be passed onto a database.

```
db=getDb()
eval = db.aaa
pipeline = [
...
{  '$match': { "xxx.yyy.zzz":ObjectId("ID")}},
...
]
```

The code used to work fine but when I try changing a variable from type ObjectId to string it stops working.

```
db=getDb()
eval = db.aaa
pipeline = [
...
{  '$match': { "xxx.yyy.zzz":{'$in': ["ID", ObjectId("ID")]}}},
...
]
```

Using string works fine when I use the query like this (in Robo, connecting to the database directly)

```
db.getCollection('evaluationResponse').aggregate([
...
{  '$match': { "xxx.yyy.zzz":{'$in': ["ID", ObjectId("ID")]}}},
...
])
```

Comment: Okay I'm actually a clown. Turns out when we migrated the data we messed up a bit. There's nothing wrong with the code.